# Vue 3 : Type 'number | boolean' is not assignable to type 'number'

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-composition-api

I am using Vue 3 with the Composition API, and I am currently trying to add Typescript in my project.

I have a "global input" component that I call to create whatever input I want. This component will then  render another input component depending on the "inputType" props. For example, I can use the global input like this :

```html
<InputBlock input-type="number" :value="15" :min="0" :max="100" />
<InputBlock input-type="check" :value="true" />
```

The InputBlock looks something like this :

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import InputNumber from "./InputNumber.vue"
import InputCheck from "./InputCheck.vue"

const props = defineProps({
  value: { type: [Boolean, Number], required: true }, // Here the value can be type Boolean|Number
  inputType: { type: String, required: true },
  // ...
})
</script>

<template>
  <InputCheck v-if="intputType === 'check'" :value="value" />
  <InputNumber v-if="intputType === 'number'" :value="value" /> <!-- Here it is supposed to be Number -->
</template>
```

And my `InputNumber` looks something like this :

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
const props = defineProps({
  value: { type: Number, required: true },
  // ...
}}
</script>
```

As you can notice, the `InputBlock` component can receive a value with different types, since this value will be use by different subcomponents. But each subcomponent can accept only one type for its `value` props. In my `InputBlock` I get this error : `Type 'number | boolean' is not assignable to type 'number'. Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'number'.`.

Do you have any idea how I can tell Typescript that the value passed in the `InputCheck` will be a Number and not Number|Boolean ? Is there a way to "force" ou "cast" the variable ? Or am doing something wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its return an error because typescript don't know that inputType.type and the value type are related.

you can try thy

```html
<template>
  <InputCheck v-if="typeof value === 'boolean'" :value="value" />
  <InputNumber v-if="typeof value === 'number'" :value="value" /> <!-- Here it is supposed to be Number -->
</template>
```

or this

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import InputNumber from "./InputNumber.vue"
import InputCheck from "./InputCheck.vue"

const props = defineProps({
  value: { type: [Boolean, Number], required: true }, // Here the value can be type Boolean|Number
})

const isBoolean = (value: any) => typeof value === "boolean"
const isNumber = (value: any) => typeof value === "number"

</script>

<template>
  <InputCheck v-if="isBoolean(value)" :value="value" />
  <InputNumber v-else-if="isNumber(value)" :value="value" /> <!-- Here it is supposed to be Number -->
</template>
```